# How to add line-break inside amsmath align section?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath, line-spacing

I'm trying to replicate the following image inside LaTeX:
[image: optimal LaTeX rendering image]

I've been successful thus far with aligning everything in the right place, but am still having trouble adding a line break within one of these "sections".

```
\begin{align*}
 & \text{(P4)} \quad \text{(Commutative law for addition)}         \;   & a & +b=b+a             \\
 & \text{(P5)} \quad \text{(Associative law for multiplication)}   \;   & a & *(b*c)=(a*b)*c  
\end{align*}
```

which yields:
[image: current LaTeX image]

I've tried adding the line break command in the middle of "multiplication", but it messed up all of the formatting. Is there a way to accomplish this within the align section, or is using a table the only way to obtain this result?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place the material that explains P5 in a `\parbox` whose maximal width is given by the width of the material that explains P4. In the `\mybox` macro defined below, the permissible width is obtained by executing `\widthof` on the first argument of the macro.

[image]

Oh, I would also replace the instances of `*` that denote multiplication with `\cdot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'align*' env.
\usepackage{calc}     % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcommand\mybox[2]{\parbox[t]{\widthof{\upshape #1}}{\upshape\RaggedRight #2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 & \textup{(P4)} \quad 
   \textup{(Commutative law for addition)} 
   && a +b=b+a             \\
 & \textup{(P5)} \quad 
   \mybox{(Commutative law for addition)}{(Associative law for multiplication)}   
   && a \cdot (b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot c  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```